# Apply readlink to a non-symlink file?

Tags: symlink, readlink, dirname

This code [from Stack Overflow](//stackoverflow.com/a/920834/156458) is to get the pathname  to the parent directory of a script inside the script, even if the script is run via a symlink to it:

```
if [ -L $0 ] ; then
    DIR=$(dirname $(readlink -f $0)) ;
else
    DIR=$(dirname $0) ;
fi ;
```

Is the above code equivalent to

```
DIR=$(dirname $(readlink -f $0)) ;
```

i.e. is there really a need to test if `$0` is a symlink, and run different commands if yes and if no?

Why not just use `$(dirname $(readlink -f $0))` regardless of  whether `$0` contains symlink or not?

Specifically, if `$0` contains symlink, then it is perfect to use `$(dirname $(readlink -f $0))`.

if `$0` is not a symlink, then it seems perfect to me to just use `$(dirname $(readlink -f $0))`:

- `$(readlink -f $0)` returns the absolute path of `$0`,  and `$(dirname $(readlink -f $0))`  returns the absolute path to the parent directory of `$0`
- `$(dirname $0)`    returns a path to the parent of `$0`, whether the return is an absolute or relative path depending on if `$0` is an absolute or relative path.
- I don't think whether  the value of `DIR` is an absolute or relative path is important in the original code, because in either case, the value of `DIR` refers to the parent directory of `$0`. So are `$(dirname $(readlink -f $0))` and `$(dirname $0)` equivalent in the original code?

Thanks.

Comment: `readlink -f` appears to allow you to specify a format on MacOS rather than 'force'. If the desired behavior is to get the real path of the given file, consider using `realpath` if available or `readlink "$0" || echo "$0"` for something more portable.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `"$0"` and `dirname "$()"`.

The commands are not equivalent because the shell test affects only the last component in the path but `readlink -f` affects all path levels.

```
mkdir physdir
touch physdir/file
ln -s physdir symlink
test -L symlink/file ; echo $?
    1
test -L symlink ; echo $?
    0
dirname symlink/file
    symlink
dirname "$(readlink -f symlink/file)"
    /crypto/home/hl/tmp/stackexchange/readlink/physdir
```

So for relative paths the output is quite different but even for absolute paths the symlink directories within differ.

Comment: Thanks. Still not sure about my question "If `$0` is not a symlink, then are `$(dirname $(readlink -f $0))` and `$(dirname $0) `equivalent?"  see my edit

Comment: What do you mean by "the shell test affects only the last component in the path" and "readlink -f affects all path levels"?

Comment: @Tim See my edit.

Comment: Thanks. I see. I just clarified my question, see my edit.

Comment: My question is actually: Why not just use `$(dirname $(readlink -f $0))` regardless of whether `$0` contains symlink or not?

Comment: @Tim Is anyone saying you should not use it? If the output is what you want then just use it...

Comment: What is the purpose of the original code which treats `$0` differently depending on whether the last component of `$0` is a symlink, if its purpose is not the same as that of using `$(dirname $(readlink -f $0))` regardless of whether `$0` contains symlink or not?

Comment: @Tim I do not know the purpose of your code.

Comment: The purpose of the original code which test `-L $0` and treats `$0` differently based on the test is to get the pathname to the parent directory of a script inside the script, evne if the script is run via a symlink to it. I was wondering if the code can be simplified to using `$(dirname $(readlink -f $0))`regardless of whether `$0` contains symlink or not

Answer (score 2):

I think whether there's a difference or not depends on the exact flavor of unix that you're using. On OSX for example, readlink doesn't have a `-f` flag and states:

> If the given argument is not a symbolic link, readlink will print nothing and exit with an error

If you know that your OS supports the `-f` flag then there shouldn't be any difference.

In fact the [-m](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/readlink.1.html) flag might be the most flexible one to use.